# Layout gravity is ignored after .setLayoutParams

Tags: android, xml

As title says. I need to put button to the right bottom corner what can be done in xml by:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
```

Since I needed some margins which are changed dynamically to keep the button always at the exact part of the image I did this in java:

```
// get and then set button params
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonParams.setMargins(0, paddingTopFollowers, paddingRight, 0);
        talkBtn.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
```

The button is down as I wanted because there is `paddingTopFollowers` but it is not on the right side. Even though if I add this line: `talkBtn.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
buttonParams.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

as part of your `buttonParams` configuration.